# How to encrypt fields present in the class annotated with @Entity annotation in spring boot application

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
 @Entity("client")
 public class Client{
     @column("client_name")
     private String clientName;
    //setter and getters
 }
```

How do I encrypt the client name and store it in db?

Comment: You can use a converter. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters. In the converter, you should encrypt before insert and decrypt after load.

Comment: Thanks sir, i tried this solution it work but ,when i'm tries to use finder methods like repo.findByClientName(clientName) it will thougth error related to encryption